# How solve for y in this equation with (y + x) in the denominator

Tags: algebra-precalculus, conic-sections

I have rearranged the general form for conic sections, trying to solve it for $y$:
$$ 
y = \frac{-Ax^2 - Dx - F}{Bx + Cy + E} 
$$

Where $A, B, C, D, E$, and $F$ are constants.

As all can see, there is a $y$ in the denominator that is added to $x$, and I can't figure out how to isolate $y$ on the left and $x$ on the right. Can someone help me understand what to do here?

Note: I tried to get Wolfram Alpha to help me, but I couldn't figure out how to make it do so.

Comment: If you multiply the denominator you can solve a quadratic equation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This won't work. Instead you have to rearrange the general form to show that it is a quadratic polynomial in $y$:
$$
Ax^2 + Bxy + Cy^2 + Dx + Ey + F 
= Cy^2 + (Bx + E)y + (Ax^2 + Dx + F).
$$
This is of the form $ay^2 + by + c$ with
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned} 
a &= C \\
b &= Bx + E \\
c &= Ax^2 + Dx + F 
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
so you can substitute these expressions into the quadratic formula to find for a given $x$ at most $2$ values of $y$.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that $Bx + Cy + E \neq 0$ the equation is equivalent to the equation
$$
  y(Bx + Cy + E) = - A x^2 - Dx - F,
$$
or
$$
  y(Bx + Cy + E) + A x^2 + Dx + F = 0,
$$
$$
 A x^2 + B xy + C y^2 + Dx + Ey + F = 0. \tag{*} \label{eq}
$$
This is a general equation of a quadratic curve, and so it has infinitely many solutions $(x,y) \in \mathbb C^2$. You can ask, how much $y$ has to be for each value $x$, or what is the function $y(x)\in \mathbb C$ so that $(x,y(x)) \in \mathbb C^2$ is part of the solution curve. That is however easy as equation \eqref{eq} can be seen as a quadratic equation in terms of $y$ (regarding $x$ as a constant)
$$
  C y^2 + (Bx+E) y + (A x^2 + Dx + F) = 0.
$$
Plugging into the well-known formula for a solution of quadratic equation:
$$
y_{1,2} = \frac{-(Bx+E) \pm \sqrt{(B x+E)^2 - 4C (A x^2 + Dx + F)}}{2C},
$$
provided by that $C\neq 0$, in which case
$$
y = -\frac{A x^2 + Dx + F}{Bx+E},
$$
unless $Bx+E=0$ as well -- in which case there is either no solution or all $y\in \mathbb C$ solve it.

Note: If you are interested only in real-valued solutions, then you need the determinant $(B x+E)^2 - 4C (A x^2 + Dx + F)$ to be nonnegative.

Comment: Corrected a typo in the OQ. What was 13 is now E. (to be in the general form of a conic section)

Comment: I edited my answer to include $E$.